# set live wallpaper fix image (do not want scroll in image - like static live wallpaper)

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Hi i am creating live wallpaper application in that in background image is changing after some time but the problem is image is getting stretched and scrolling, i want image to fix at one screen only it must not be scrolled, below is my code can any body help me how to set

```
  public static void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap mBitmap,Context mActivity, int height, int width)
  {
    try{
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(mActivity);  

        if (mBitmap != null) {  
            try {
                mBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, height, width, true);

                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {  

            }  
        }
```

by this function i am setting the image as an live wall paper here what should i have to pass in both **height and width**  so i can get picture which is not scrolling

for example if my phone screen resolution is 480x320 then if i pass this in height and width but can not get proper image, the image is still scrolling

i have used one function also for scrolling the wallpaper that is below

```
 WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

with this i am getting width and height and i have passed this value in above function but still image is scrolling in live wallpaper! so what should i have to pass in width & height so image can not be scrolled and fix in one screen